# How to parse column values into multiple rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes and the format is this:

```
a|b|c   label       1003252452  20210929
```

There may be one column in a df that is delimited by a vertical bar |. I want to split this row into 3 rows, with all other columns remaining the same:

```
id  tag         uid         date
a   label       1003252452  20210929
b   label       1003252452  20210929
c   label       1003252452  20210929
```

Also after they are split, there might be duplicate rows due to the split, duplicate rows should be removed. Is there a good way to do this? I am thinking to approach this way:

```
for df in all_dfs:
      dict_rows = []
      for index, row in df.iterrows():
        new_rows = []
        if 'id' in row:
           row_dict = dict(row)
           tags = row_dict['id'].split('|')
            for tag in tags:
                 new_row = {'id': tag}
                 del row_dict['id']
                 
                        ...
```

This may be possible, but very complicated. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` + `explode` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.assign(id = df.id.str.split('|')).explode('id').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

  id    tag         uid      date
0  a  label  1003252452  20210929
1  b  label  1003252452  20210929
2  c  label  1003252452  20210929
```

Comment: That looks great. Does this work if 'id' doesn't exist in a specific df? Also, I don't want the 3 '0' in each row.

Comment: What do you mean `id` doesn't exist ? You can use `.reset_index(drop=True)` to remove duplicated index.

Comment: I mean some df may have the 'id' column, and some may not have this column. I have multiple dfs to do this operation.

Comment: This requires the `id` column. You can check if `id` in the data frame in the `for` loop, something like `for df in all_dfs: if 'id' in df:  do split else: noop`

Comment: I am iterating each df and only do this if there is an 'id' column. if there is no way to do this existence checking in the one-line code, i will do it externally in the first for loop.

Comment: Yeah, I will do the check under the `for` loop and. apply this only when there's an `id` column.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want

```
>>> df
      id    tag         uid      date
0  a|b|c  label  1003252452  20210929
>>> df.drop('id', axis=1).join(df['id'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('id'))
     tag         uid      date id
0  label  1003252452  20210929  a
0  label  1003252452  20210929  b
0  label  1003252452  20210929  c
```